# Can $\cos(36^\circ)$ be calculated using derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

Can $\cos(36°)$ be calculated using known cosines like $\cos(37°)$ and the derivative formula $$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+ Δx) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
?

(We have to let $f(x):=\cos(x)$, so we can let $x=37°$, or in radian form, and let $f(x+\Delta x)$ be $\cos(x+\Delta x)$ and $\Delta x=-1°$ or in radian form, so we can say $\cos(37°-1°)$. I just do not know the process. I understand it is approximate, but I cannot calculate it approximately.

Comment: Is this in degrees?

Comment: I'm quite surprise that you know $\cos(37)$...

Comment: How would you calculate $\cos{(37+\Delta x)}$ if you only have the known value of $\cos{(37)}$ ?

Comment: Yes it is in degrees. My deepest apologies for not knowing formula scripts. I just want knowledge in derivatives. Please forgive me. Cos(37deg) is 0.8 and Sin(37deg) is 0.6 we had to learn it at school.

Comment: the cosine of $36°$ is really special: $$\cos(36°)=\frac{\varphi}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{4}$$

Comment: @AlirezaHonarvar But, actually $$\cos(37°)\not=0.8$$

Comment: @AlirezaHonarvar $\cos(37^\circ)=0.7986\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you kind people for pointing my mistake out! I had been mistaking for thinking Cos(37deg)=0.8 while it was not! I hope you can forgive me. I learnt something new today! :)

Comment: Would you consider a use of Taylor series a calculation using derivatives? Since $\cos x,\,\sin x$ both solve $y^{\prime\prime}=-y$ (if you work in radians), the result is equivalent to using a compound angle formula. And since $1^\circ$ is small, its sine and cosine can easily be approximated with Taylor polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we know that $\cos{(37^\circ)}\approx 0.8$ and $\sin{(37^\circ)}\approx 0.6$ then we can use the fact that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \cos{(x)}=-\sin{(x)}$$
to approximate $\cos{(36^\circ)}$ as
$$\cos{(36^\circ)}\approx 0.8+0.6(\frac\pi{180}) = 0.810...$$
Where $1^\circ = \frac\pi{180}$ radians which must be used here.